# Node Inspector slow starting

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-inspector, nodemon

I have finally got `node-inspector` to work with nodemon nicely, however `node-inspector` is taking about 60/90's to load all of the assets and actually become connecting.

This is just a case of having a heavy backend (which I don't think i particularly do) or is there something wrong in my setup :(?

```
cmd > node-inspector
    > //Node Inspector v0.12.3
    > //Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/?ws=127.0.0.1:8080&port=5858 to start debugging.

new cmd > nodemon --debug --delay 0.1 ./bin/www
```

So running correctly and site loads I'll then make changes to the code and the server will reload my changes and `node-inspector`will reload and take forever :(

How can I make it load instantly like a cheetah or a runner bean? Just lightning fast!